# How do I combine multiple dataframes from a json file using an api and a for loop? (python)

Tags: python, json, dataframe, api, loops

I am trying to download financial ratio data for more than one company ticker and save the data to one data frame. I have used a function to interact with the API and download the json file, then I am trying to make a for loop to iterate through the dictionary of tickers.

```
api_key = 'API KEY REMOVED FOR PRIVACY'

def get_ratios(stock):
    url = (f'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/ratios/{stock}?limit=40&apikey={api_key}')
    x = pd.read_json(url)
    return x
```

Using just the function get_ratios('AAPL') returns a dataframe, but I want to be able to retrieve data for multiple tickers, not just AAPL.
[image: get_ratios('AAPL')]
I have tried to create a for loop to be able to retrieve data for multiple tickers. When I try save the function to a dataframe only the data for AAN saves.. so I think it must be overwriting the data for AAPL. I am unsure how to fix this, I have tried to create another for loop to .append the dataframe y to itself, but I just get an error back.

```
ticker = ['AAPL','AAN']
for i in ticker:
    y = get_ratios(i)
```

But when I don't save get_ratios(i) to a list and run it as shown below, I get a list of both AAPL and AAN data.

```
ticker = ['AAPL','AAN']
for i in ticker:
    print(get_ratios(i))
```

symbol       date period  currentRatio  quickRatio  cashRatio  
0    AAPL 2020-09-26     FY      1.363604    1.218195   0.360710
1    AAPL 2019-09-28     FY      1.540126    1.384447   0.462022
2    AAPL 2018-09-29     FY      1.123843    0.986566   0.221733
3    AAPL 2017-09-30     FY      1.276063    1.089670   0.201252

[image: what comes out of the function without saving it to a dataframe - showing AAN after the AAPL data]

Answer (score 0):

Put the dataframes returnet by `get_ratios()` to a list and as a final step do [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat) to concat the dataframes to one. For example:

```py
ticker = ["AAPL", "AAN"]

df_list = []
for i in ticker:
    df_list.append(get_ratios(i))

df_final = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line using list comprehension and `pd.concat`, you can do:

```
df = pd.concat([get_ratios(t) for t in ticker])
```